# OpenCV: Buffering IplImage*'s to share between pthreads

Tags: c, pointers, opencv, iplimage

I've been grinding at trying to get a circular buffer working for days, and it's just not playing ball for some reason. I'm writing the program in C, not C++.

I'm trying to buffer images from a camera in one thread, so it can be read and processed in another thread (I know about how to use pthread_mutex_* for resource locking). So far, I've managed buffer images onto my buffer but I'm having issues retrieving them. This is my circular buffer implementation:

```
#define BUFFER_SIZE 100

typedef struct
{
     IplImage** queue[BUFFER_SIZE];
     IplImage** in;
     IplImage** out;
     int num_frames;
     int in_ctr;
     int out_ctr;
     int update_flag;
 } frame_buffer;

static frame_buffer frbuff;

void buff_init()
{
    frbuff.in = &frbuff.queue[0];
    frbuff.out = &frbuff.queue[0];
    frbuff.num_frames = 0;
    frbuff.in_ctr = 0;
    frbuff.out_ctr = 0;
    frbuff.update_flag = 0;
}

int buff_size()
{
    return frbuff.num_frames;
}

int buff_flag_check()
{
    return frbuff.update_flag;
}

void buff_flag_set()
{
    frbuff.update_flag = 1;
}

void buff_flag_clr()
{
    frbuff.update_flag = 0;
}

IplImage** buff_get()
{
    IplImage** nextfr;
    if(frbuff.num_frames == 0)
    {
        return NULL;
    }
    nextfr = frbuff.out++;
    if(++frbuff.out_ctr == BUFFER_SIZE)
    {
        frbuff.out = &frbuff.queue[0];
        frbuff.out_ctr = 0;
    }
    --frbuff.num_frames;
    buff_flag_clr();
    return nextfr;
}

int buff_put(IplImage* nextfr)
{
    if(++frbuff.num_frames > BUFFER_SIZE)
    {
       return 0;
    }
    frbuff.in++; 
    frbuff.in = nextfr;
    if(++frbuff.in_ctr == BUFFER_SIZE)
    {
        frbuff.in = &frbuff.queue[0];
        frbuff.in_ctr = 0;
    }
    buff_flag_set();
    return 1;
}
```

I can buff_put() just fine, this appears to work as I'm seeing the counter increase. When I buff_get(), I also get something that's not null. The issue comes when I try to do anything with it:

```
IplImage **some_image;
some_image = buff_get();
cvShowImage("some_window_somewhere",some_image);
```

Well apparently it's unhappy with that...

```
OpenCV Error: Bad flag (parameter or structure field) (Unrecognized or unsupported array type) in cvGetMat, file /home/fagg/src/OpenCV-2.3.1/modules/core/src/array.cpp, line 2482
 terminate called after throwing an instance of 'cv::Exception'
 what():  /home/fagg/src/OpenCV-2.3.1/modules/core/src/array.cpp:2482: error: (-206)  Unrecognized or unsupported array type in function cvGetMat
```

I also tried this (which results in a segmentation fault):

```
cvShowImage("some_window_somewhere",*some_image);
```

I'm very stuck, have tried everything I can think of. No doubt it will end up being something obvious (I hate pointers). Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Switch on **all** your compiler´s warnings, **read** them and you might get enlightened ... ;-)

Comment: "throwing an instance of 'cv::Exception'" looks like C++, not C. So does ".cpp" in the filename. They are different languages, although this may not be relevant here.

Comment: btw: hate never was, never is and never will be a good guide ...

Comment: @mlp: I'm using the C API of OpenCV. I have no idea why it shows up as .cpp, but I'm definitely using C. I'm very new to OpenCV so I hope I've configured it correctly.

Comment: @alk: It compiles, the error it throws is a runtime error. The compiler seems happy, it throws this error once it gets to "cvShowImage()" in one of the threads (the thread which calls buff_get()).

Comment: @Ashton Fagg: Which platform are you working on, using which compiler?

Comment: does it have to be C? Why not use C++?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am going to make an assumption here and assuming you are trying to build a queue of ImpImage*'s.  If that is the case, this line:

```
IplImage** queue[BUFFER_SIZE];
```

should read:

```
IplImage* queue[BUFFER_SIZE];
```

And these lines:

```
IplImage** buff_get()
{
    IplImage** nextfr;
    if(frbuff.num_frames == 0)
    {
        return NULL;
    }
    nextfr = frbuff.out++;
```

should read:

```
IplImage* buff_get()
{
    IplImage* nextfr;
    if(frbuff.num_frames == 0)
    {
        return NULL;
    }
    nextfr = *frbuff.out++;
```

And these lines:

```
IplImage **some_image;
some_image = buff_get();
cvShowImage("some_window_somewhere",some_image);
```

should read:

```
IplImage *some_image;
some_image = buff_get();
cvShowImage("some_window_somewhere",some_image);
```

Next we have a straightforward bug.  This line:

```
frbuff.in = nextfr;
```

should read:

```
*frbuff.in = nextfr;
```

I am surprised a modern C compiler didn't reject the code outright.  At the very least it must be giving a warnings.  If you are using gcc I suggest passing -Wall -Wextra as a minimum for all new code you write.  Getting your code into a form the compiler accepts without warnings may be painful, but in the long run as you are discovering not doing that is even more painful.

Secondly, you say you are using pthreads.  Most of your code will be OK *if* buf_get() is always called from the same thread, and likewise for buf_put().  If buf_get() is called from more than one thread then at the very least your queue will be corrupted, and ditto for buf_put().  The one exception to all this is frbuff.update_flag which is altered from both buf_get() and buf_put().  If buf_get() and buf_put() are called from different threads you can be assured update_flag will end up containing the wrong thing.

Comment: buff_get() and buff_put() are called by seperate threads. One thread does not call both. I'm getting lock on a mutex before I do anything relating to the buffer -> initialising, getting, putting etc. I also set up the Makefile to include -Wextra., and managed to fix up a few warnings (now it's just warnings about unused parameters, which is fine because that part hasn't been written yet).

I've fixed the code with what you suggested (thank you!) and it now doesn't give that error at runtime. The issue I get now is that buff_get() seems to return NULL. I'm working on that now.